# Redirection through .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I am developing a PHP website  and I want to redirect php to html and I write the below code in htaccess file. Code is working fine and all the php pages are redirect to html but when I put file name with php in url site is also open with .

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.html$ $1.php [nc]
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace your code with this:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s/+(.+?)\.php[?\s] [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1.html [R=301,L]

RewriteRule ^(.+?)\.html$ /$1.php [L,NC]
```